# GC in .Net4: Specifying gcServer and gcConcurrent together

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

I was performance tuning our server, and tried specifying the following config, as well as setting `GCLatencyMode` to `LowLatency`.

```
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
<runtime>
  <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  <gcConcurrent enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

This gave me a performance increase, and I was pretty pleased until a colleague pointed out that the two settings are mutually exclusive in .Net 4.

So what configuration will this resolve to? Certainly, `GCSettings.IsServerGC` returns true, and there's a very measurable performance gain from setting `gcConcurrent` to false.

(I compiled the code I was profiling into a test harness, so although it's usually a server hosted by IIS, all my timings were on a console application)

Comment: Did you get anwer to your query from anywhere else? I am planning to configure my application on similar lines.

Comment: @vibhu - no, no conclusive answer. Of course, .Net 4.5 now supports background garbage collection

Answer (score 7):

I have found your answer here:
[Latency Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384202(v=vs.100).aspx)

> Default Garbage Collection Modes
>
> ---
>
> If the LatencyMode property is not specified, the default mode is concurrent workstation garbage collection. The mode is dependent on the value of two runtime configuration settings:
>
> **<gcConcurrent>**
>
> If enabled, this setting specifies that the common language runtime runs workstation garbage collection on a separate thread to support concurrent operations. This setting is enabled by default.
>
> **<gcServer>**
>
> If enabled, this setting specifies that the common language runtime runs server garbage collection; otherwise, it runs workstation garbage collection. You can enable server garbage collection only on computers with two or more processors. It is not enabled by default. If this setting is enabled, **gcConcurrent** is automatically disabled.
>
> The default values for **GCLatencyMode** are as follows:
>
> Interactive when **gcConcurrent** is enabled and **gcServer** is disabled.
>
> Batch when **gcConcurrent** is disabled, or **gcServer** is enabled.

Thus, when gcServer is enabled, gcConcurrent is automatically disabled. No need to set gcConcurrent to disabled. GCLatencymode runs in batch mode which exaplains the performance increase.

Comment: See @Narayana answer, the settings are not mutually exclusive in .NET 4.5+

Answer (score 3):

If this is any help now, gcConcurrent setting is used interchangably with background GC in .NET 4.5. The [following MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/07/20/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps.aspx) explains the settings available in .NET 4.5. You can use all settings together, and they are available for both workstation as well as server GC.

> While the SustainedLowLatency setting is in effect, generation 0,
>   generation 1, and background generation 2 collections still occur and
>   do not typically cause noticeable pause times. A blocking generation 2
>   collection happens only if the machine is low in memory or if the app
>   induces a GC by calling GC.Collect().

Also,

> In the .NET Framework 4.5, SustainedLowLatency mode is available for
>   both workstation and server GC. To turn it on, set the
>   GCSettings.LatencyMode property to GCLatencyMode.SustainedLowLatency.
>   The .NET Framework 4 includes a LowLatency mode for workstation GC;
>   however, this setting is only intended to be used for short periods of
>   time, whereas SustainedLowLatency mode is intended to be used for much
>   longer.

Comment: Link is now https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-net-framework-4-5-includes-new-garbage-collector-enhancements-for-client-and-server-apps/